# Bounding box in mapbox.js

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have a spatial database with thousands of polygons distributed across a country. I want to display those polygons in a mapbox or a leaflet map. However, a simple query that retrieves all of the objects in the database is a massive load for the network and takes a long time, and when it finally loads it takes much of the RAM just holding the geojson object.

I want to solve this more intelligently by querying only the objects that fall within the current map viewport. To this end, I modified my REST service to receive a polygon and using it to filter the queryset (I am using Django REST). This is already working, what I can't figure out is how to obtain the extent of the current viewport.

Does mapbox.js expose this functionality? How can I solve this?

By the way, I am using mapbox.js instead of mapboxgl only because of omnivore support as I am using the well known text format. I am in an early development stage so if this is easier to solve with another library I am open to considering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have noticed, mapbox.js extends Leaflet.

Therefore you should be able to use the [`map.getBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getbounds) method to retrieve the extent of the current viewport.

> Returns the geographical bounds visible in the current map view

Typically you would listen to the [`"moveend"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-moveend) event and perform your query.

> Fired when the center of the map stops changing (e.g. user stopped dragging the map).

Example:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

map.on('moveend', function() {
  console.log(map.getBounds().toBBoxString());
});

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't looking in the right place, thanks a lot. This was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: how do I include this in my webmap?

Comment: By reading the post and doing the thing Gokul. Its all right there.